# How do I change the location of DivX cache files?

Tags: windows-xp

I recently installed to the latest version of DivX and suddenly found my C drive filling up with the cache files. I tracked it down to:

C:\Files\My Videos\DivX Movies\Temporary Downloaded Files

My old laptop (running WinXP) only has a small hard drive and any DivX cache files fills it up so I want it to use my D drive where I have a little more room. The trouble is I can't see anywhere in the DivX preferences where I can change the cache location.

**Can anyone tell me how I can change the location of the DivX cache files?**

Comment: Easy, don't use DivX

Comment: You could use sybolic links(don't know whether it works in xp). <http://superuser.com/a/904472/400355>, this answer explains how to do it

Answer (score 1):

DivX seems to have only one setting for its data, defaulting to ...My Videos\DivX Movies.  It puts its temporary files in a subfolder of that folder - the one you noted was filling up - Temporary Downloaded Files.

So it doesn't look like you can change the location of the temporary files folder, but you **can** change DivX's main folder, which will of course also change where the temp files are placed.  In other words, you can go into the DivX preferences and change
**C:\Files\My Videos\DivX Movies\Temporary Downloaded Files** to
**D:\DivX Movies\Temporary Downloaded Files** or something similar on D.

To do this, on the DivX menu, select File > Preferences > General, and choose a new folder for "Default Video Folder".

There are also a few options in the DivX preferences that should help to control the amount of crap that builds up.  For instance, Video Library > Auto-clear downloads from Download Manager when complete.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried that (and just double checked) but it seems that even though I've changed the default video directory to my D drive, the temp cache files still get placed in the aformentioned directory in the C drive.

Comment: Weird. That means it probably *does* have a separate setting for the temp files.  I would search the registry for items related to DivX and if you see a setting clearly pointing that that folder, try changing it.  Don't attempt any registry changes unless you're comfortable there, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the registry at the following location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\`

There should be a value for "My Video" - changing that may affect what DivX uses as your video folder (might need to restart as well).

Note: I'm assuming you're happy to change the location of your videos for all applications that use your "My Videos" folder, not just DivX...